# CSS and button design

Tags: html, css

Please help me how can I create a button that looks like this with css/html?
[image]

I currently have this code but it only show a basic button. I need to add the text inside a box indicated by `New!` in the picture. I need some help with css. What should I do?

```css
.btn {
  -webkit-border-radius: 6;
  -moz-border-radius: 6;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #3498db;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Click Me Now!</button>
```

Comment: normally the text goes inside the html tag not using css

Comment: I don't know how to do it. I thought I would need css. But if you see how to do it in html, can you please help me?

Comment: You don't know how to declare a button in the html ?

Comment: I have this `<button class="btn">Click Me Now!</button>` but that not what I want

Answer (score 1):

a css only solution if you can't change the markup is to use pseudo-elements.

```css
.btn {
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 2em;
  background: lighgrey;
  padding: 40px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.btn:after {
  content: 'New!';
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #00c8ff;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Click Me Now!</button>
```

Comment: This is looking really good. How can I make the `.btn:after's content` to be  flexible? Like If I have multiple buttons and they require different text?

Comment: i'm only using padding and margins here, it will resize as the content changes, however if there's no room for both of them to fit horizontally they will overlap, here you'll have to use media queries, to change the `font-size`

Comment: that sounds very complicated for me. I don't even know how to do that. I just look at resizing the screen and yes the text does overlap :(

Answer (score 1):

You can improve the pseudo element solution by using data attribute:

```css
.btn {
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size:20px;
  max-width:250px;
  display:inline-flex;
  vertical-align:top;
  align-items:center;
  background: grey;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.btn:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-left:5px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #00c8ff;
}
```

```html
<button data-text="first" class="btn">Click Me Now!</button>
<button data-text="second" class="btn">Click Me Now!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css would be:

```
.insideText{
      font-size: 0.50em;
      float: right;
      margin-left: 10px;
      color: orange;
      border: 1px solid;
      margin-top: -1;
}
```

And your Html:

```
    <div id="container">
        <button class="btn"><p class="insideText">Some other text</p>Some Text</button>
    </div>
```

Your .btn css would stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea, using [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) to position another element inside the button.

```css
body {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  background: #c3c3c3;
  padding: .5em;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: left;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: .6em;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.btn span {
  float: right;
  padding: .5em;
  margin: 0 0 0 .5em;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: .6em;
  background-color: #98d9ea;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.btn:hover span {
  background-color: tomato;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn">
  <span>NEW!</span>
  Click me now!
</button>


<button type="button" class="btn">
  <span>NOT NEW!</span>
  Click me at some point!
</button>
```